# Find a value in an array of objects using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array of objects say `items`. I want to find item having `name` xyz.

Currently, I wrote a for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    if( items[i].name == "xyz" ) 
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to shorten this loop to one line statement using jquery? something like this:

```
$.find(items, "name", "xyz");
```

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: No, that's just `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
var matchingItems = items.filter(function(v){return v.name=="xyz"});
```

or using jQuery (for greater compatibility, as like many Array functions, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) aren't available on IE8) :

```
var matchingItems = $.grep(items, function(v){return v.name=="xyz"});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! this is very neat and efficient.

Comment: @KevindraSingh: Don't you want to return a boolean value instead of an array?

Comment: I want the `item` object. it's returning the same.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$.grep(yourArray, function(n) { 
    return n.name == "xyz"; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [native `some` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
items.some(function(el) { return el.name == "xyz"; })
```

With jQuery, you would need to do something like [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) and then check the length (`$.grep(items, function(el){ return el.name=="xyz"; }).length > 1`) - not an optimal solution. If you want to use a library solution for those browsers that don't support `some` (and don't want to use [the polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility)), use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)'s `any`.

Comment: some isn't available on IE8.

Comment: @dystroy: I already mentioned two solutions for buggy browsers.

Comment: Those mentions weren't there when I commented. It seems this is still a needed precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.find = function( array, property, key ) {
        var found = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if( array[i][property] == key ) 
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found ? i : -1;
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Usage: `$.find(items, "name", "xyz");`

Comment: You would not put this function on `$.fn`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuerys inArray Example

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

might helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr = ["abc", "xyz" ];
        if($.inArray("abc",arr) > 0){
          return true;
        }
else 
return false
```

​

this will return the index of "searching string"

if not found, it will return -1.